# Does fastlane clear previous metadata?

Tags: xcode, build, fastlane

I am maintaining an app that was previously built manually using xCode, and it is already in the App Store with all the information in iTunes Connect already set up, such as screenshots, 'what's new in this version'section, app privacy information, etc... now I've tried setting up fastlane as described in this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/233168-fastlane-tutorial-getting-started#toc-anchor-009

But I tried on a test app, which I would describe just as a sandbox that I use to train myself using fastlane. Now the question is: if I use fastlane for an app that is already in iTunes Connect, which information gets cleared and which information will stay? to be more for example: if I don't upload any screenshot with fastlane, will my previous screenshots be deleted? if I leave the default fastlane keywords, categories, etc... will they clear the previous one? I am asking to avoid the risk of losing information.

Answer (score 0):

If you upload just the new build (new .ipa file without new information) you will not lose the old information.